# Upload file in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, file-upload

I am  creating webpart to upload file.
I created asp button:

```
<asp:Button ID="txtUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="txtUpload_Click" />
```

Then on click event of button i write

```
FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
```

But i dont get any fileopen dialog. I also wish to add filter to only select images. How can we do it? After selecting i want to upload to sharepoint document list as attachment

**Update1**

I have found this example [link](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-and-deploying-visual-web-part.html) but i want it without textbox and browse button. I just want to open file dialog on click of my button

Answer (score 0):

try below code

`<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />`

to upload use below code in the event

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
```

Comment: But this will display textbox and browse button

Comment: I don't think there is any way to open dailog for files as you wish to implement, you can try hiding the textbox and keep the button visible.

Comment: Can u tell how to hide textbox?